# Constructing a unity feedback system - not working

Tags: matlab

As far I know, for unity feedback I should use this code:

```
loop = feedback(G,1);
```

`G` is an open-loop transfer function, but when I applied this code, it shows me this problem.

```
??? Error using ==> feedback at 72

Not enough input arguments.

Error in ==> fazlay at 25
[u,v]=feedback(u1,v1,1);
```

Here is the code I wrote:

```
u1=[5400];
v1=[2 2.5 1.5];
[u,v]=feedback(u1,v1,1);
```

The system transfer function is:

```
       5400
-------------------
2 s^2 + 2.5 s + 1.5
```

Comment: The function always requires two systems, check `doc feedback`

Comment: http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/feedback.html @ daniel

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you told us how you're calling the code is one thing, but the way you're actually calling the code is another.  Specifically, you have the numerator and denominator coefficients for your transfer function, but you need to merge them into **one** transfer function first.  As such, use [`tf`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/tf.html):

```
u1=[5400]; v1=[2 2.5 1.5];
G = tf(u1, v1);
```

**Now**, use `feedback`:

```
M = feedback(G, 1)

M =

          5400
  --------------------
  2 s^2 + 2.5 s + 5402

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

If you take a look, you can simplify this TF by dividing up and down by 2.  You can achieve this simplification with [`minreal`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/control/ref/minreal.html):

```
Mmin = minreal(M)

Mmin =

         2700
  -------------------
  s^2 + 1.25 s + 2701

Continuous-time transfer function.
```

---

If you want to double-check if you got the right transfer function, you know that a closed-loop transfer function for a control system is:

[image]

Therefore, `G(s)` is what you defined previously, and `H(s) = 1`, and so you can do the calculation yourself:

```
M = G / (1 + G);
Mmin = minreal(M)

Mmin =

         2700
  -------------------
  s^2 + 1.25 s + 2701

Continuous-time transfer function.
```